# Unable to use Postgres with Docker Compose and Laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am developing a Laravel application. I am using Docker Compose to install my environment. I am using Postgres for database.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
    apache:
        container_name: easy_eat_apache
        image: webdevops/apache:ubuntu-16.04
        environment:
            WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/public
            WEB_ALIAS_DOMAIN: easy-eat.localhost
            WEB_PHP_SOCKET: php-fpm:9000
        volumes: # Only shared dirs to apache (to be served)
        - ./public:/var/www/public:cached
        - ./storage:/var/www/storage:cached
        networks:
        - easy-eat-network
        ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    php-fpm:
        container_name: easy_eat_php
        image: jguyomard/laravel-php:7.2
        volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/
        - ./ci:/var/www/ci:cached
        - ./vendor:/var/www/vendor:delegated
        - ./storage:/var/www/storage:delegated
        - ./node_modules:/var/www/node_modules:cached
        - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh:cached
        - ~/.composer/cache:/root/.composer/cache:delegated
        networks:
        - easy-eat-network
    db:
        image: postgres
        restart: always
        ports:
        - 5432
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
        volumes:
        - easy-eat-data:/var/lib/postgresql
networks:
    easy-eat-network:
        driver: "bridge"
volumes:
    easy-eat-data:
        driver: "local"
```

In the env file of Laravel, I put the database credentials like this

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=postgres
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Then I run migration command to see if my application is able to connect to the postgres. I got this error.

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations)

  at /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired")
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  2   PDO::__construct("pgsql:host=db;dbname=postgres;port=5432;sslmode=prefer", "postgres", "secret", [])
      /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `php-fpm` container is attached to the `easy-eat-network` network, but your `db` container isn't, so it will get attached to the default network Docker Compose creates instead.  That will cause problems resolving and routing between the containers.

Probably the easiest solution here is just to rely on the default network Docker Compose will create for you.  Delete all of the `networks:` blocks, both at the top level and individual services.

If you really want to explicitly declare the network yourself, then you need to add the `networks: [easy-eat-network]` stanza to the `db:` service block.